# Fancyhr warning \footskip is too small

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm stumbling on this warning in overleaf. I am importing the package `fancyhdr` but I am not using `\footskip` operator. So I'm not sure why I'm shown this warning.

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \footskip is too small (0.0pt): Make it at least 4.08003pt. We now make it that large for the rest of the document. This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Comment: Add `\setlength{\footskip}{5pt}` in your preamble (before `\begin{document}`) ...

Comment: you should always show some code. Either you have set `\footskip` to 0pt or you are using a non standard class that has not set `\footskip`

Comment: curious why overleaf tag was removed if I'm observing this in overleaf @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @koleygr that helped me get rid of the warning! mighty thanks!

Comment: @ChaitanyaBapat it is completely unrelated to the machine on which you run tex. If you provided an example and I ran it on this laptop or at texlive.net or anywhere, you would get the same error. the overleaf tag is for issues specific to overleaf

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
\setlength{\footskip}{5pt}
```

in your preamble i.e. before

```
\begin{document}
```

As correctly pointed out in the comment by @koleygr